# JDialog Not Resizing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I am opening a JDialog from a JFrame when a button is pressed and this is my code for doing so.

```
   private JDialog FindView; ~~> JDialog declaration. 

   private void jMenuItem9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
    if (FindView == null) {
        JFrame mainFrame = myApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
        FindView = new MyAppFindView(mainFrame, true);
        FindView.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
    }
    myApp.getApplication().show(FindView);
}
```

but the JDialog always opens in the same size. How can I resize the JDialog?

I checked the `Form Size Policy` and it is `Generate pack()`.

This is the size I have set it to in my FindView java file.

[image]

and this is the size it opens in.

[image: This is the default size the dialog opens in]

**SOLVED**

The last line of code seemed to cause the problem.
Replacing the code with `FindView.setVisible(true);` solved the problem.

Comment: Call pack before you place it or show it

Comment: You mean you want the JDialog to open with different sizes, or you want to be able to resize it after it opens?

Comment: try setResizable(true) method, may help you.

Comment: @AliAlamiri I just want it to open in the size that i have set it to.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have done that and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE.  The problem is in your code.

Comment: @jzd what is the problem?

Comment: My answer may solve your problem.

Comment: @AliAlamiri sorry, it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
JFrame mainFrame = myApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
FindView = new MyAppFindView(mainFrame, true);
FindView.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
FindView.setPreferredSize(yourDimensions);
```